# Get instance variable values from ArrayList Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class Employee{

  public String name;

}
```

and

```
public static void main(){

    Employee e1= new Employee();
    e1.name="AAA";

    Employee e2= new Employee();
    e2.name="BBB";

    Employee e3= new Employee();
    e3.name="CCC";

    Employee e4= new Employee();
    e4.name="DDD";

    ArrayList<Employee> al= new ArrayList<>();

    al.add(e1);
    al.add(e2);
    al.add(e3);
    al.add(e4);
}
```

Now, I need to Iterate through the ArrayList and get the name property of each object. How can I do that. is there any direct method to do that???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a for-each loop to accomplish that:

```
for (Employee employee : al) {
   System.out.println(employee.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do in 3 ways,

A simple iterative approach is

```
for(int i = 0,j = al.size(); i < j; i++) {
    System.out.println(al.get(i).name);
}
```

Using an enhanced for loop

```
for(Employee emp : al) {
   System.out.println(emp.name);
}
```

Using an iterator :

```
Iterator<Employee> itr = al.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    emp = itr.next();
    System.out.println(emp.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println(al.get(index).name);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator<Employee> i=al.getIterator();
 while (i.hasNext()) {
  String name = i.next().name;
}
```